# How to send status code with message .NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working with two Web API projects. I am getting response from one API to another API with status code and message. Using following method I need to send status code with message.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> CreateOrder(Order order)
{
        string jsonResponse = null;
        HttpClient client = new();

        var payload = new JsonPayloadBody();
        payload.Api = new Api();
        payload.Header = new OrderHeader();

        payload.Api.NAME = "CREATE";
        payload.Api.QUERY = "CREATE_ORDER";

        payload.Header.INTERFACE_RECORD_ID = order.INTERFACE_RECORD_ID;            
        payload.Header.INTERFACE_ACTION_CODE = order.INTERFACE_ACTION_CODE;                                                                               

        payload.LineItems.Add(li); }

        var orderPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
        var payloadObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MHScaleMessage>(orderPayload);
        var requestPayload = payloadObj.ToJsonString();
        var stringContent = new StringContent(requestPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(_baseUrl, stringContent);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
             jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation(jsonResponse);
            _logger.LogInformation("Order created successfully");
        }
        else
        {         
            _logger.LogInformation("Order creation filed");
        }

        return jsonResponse;
}
```

Using this line

```
jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I was able to send message to postman but it's sending 200 status code always. So I need to send status code according to the response, for example:

```
return NotFound 
return Ok 
return BadRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are `A Web Api` and `B Wen Api`. You use `A` to get the response from `B` with status code. `A`'s task is to get the status code of `B`. The reason you also get 200 status code is whatever `B`'s status code , `A` can always successfully get the status code , So `A` always return 200.

If you want to add different response message from `A` , you can add some code like:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     _logger.LogInformation(jsonResponse);
     _logger.LogInformation("Order created successfully");
}
else if(response.StatusCode == (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)404)
{
     //..add NotFound message......
}
else if(response.StatusCode == (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)400)
{
     //..add BadRequest message......
}
      //......
```

if you want to return status code, you can add the following code

```
[HttpPost]
//if you want to get the status codo , you need to return a StatusCodeResult Class in your action 
//so i change Task<string> to Task<IActionResult>
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateOrder(Order order)
{
    //......

    else if(response.StatusCode == (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)400)
        {
             //if you want to use jsonResponse to do some logger,you can try this 
             jsonResponse  = "BadRequest"
             _logger.LogInformation(jsonResponse);
             return BadRequest(jsonResponse  );
        }
}
```

**Notice** : Here is a problem when you use above code to create Badrequest , When you get the 400 status code from `A` Web Api , You don't know if the problem is in `A` or in `B`.

Comment: Hi thank you form your answer. If I use second option. finally want I can return i mean if i use this (return jsonResponse;) its saying cannot convert string. so as a final return what can i return.

Comment: Hi , @user17870723, You can see I change the Task<string> to Task<IActionResult> , so in this action ,you can't just return a parameter of type string . I have edited my asnwer to give a more detailed explanation。

Comment: Thank you. I got your point. Now its working. Thanks for your support